# Cumulative Sum using next column/row in R

Tags: r, sum, row

I am having trouble with maybe something easy but I just can't find the solution.

Suppos I have an initial value of 1,000 for a variable called **TOTAL** and using another column I would like to do a cumulative sum, either negative or positive values.

The problem is that I do not want to do it manually but reproducible.

This is an expected output:

```
Profit  TOTAL
1  -10.0  990       #Started with 1,000
2   16.3 1006.3     #990 + 16.3
3  -10.0  996.3     #1006.3 - 10
4  -10.0  986.3     #And so on....
5   14.0 1000.3
6  -10.0  990.3
```

I tried to use cumsum function but I don't have an idea of how to implement it:

```
df %>% mutate(cumsum = cumsum(Profit)))
```

And I tried with sapply but I failed:

```
sapply(df[,c("TOTAL")], function(x) df$Profit[x+2] + df$TOTAL[x+1])
```

Any function, suggestion, or package that could solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your right you need simply

```
df=data.frame(profit=c(-10,16.3,-10,-10,14,-10))
total=1000
df$TOTAL=total+cumsum(df$profit)

 profit  TOTAL
1  -10.0  990.0
2   16.3 1006.3
3  -10.0  996.3
4  -10.0  986.3
5   14.0 1000.3
6  -10.0  990.3
```

Comment: Something really simple that I couldn't figure out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It could also be that the dplyr package needs to be explicitly set when calling mutate.

```
df %>% dplyr::mutate(cumsum = cumsum(Profit)))
```

Although 1000 would still need to be added to this as a second step.

Answer (score 0):

With base R you can use the `transform` function along with the base R `cumsum` function. For example

```
transform(d, TOTAL = 1000 + cumsum(Profit))
```