# R: Cumulative Sums

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language. Suppose I have the following dataset:

```
a = abs(rnorm(10,10,10))

b = abs(rnorm(10, 6, 7))

c = abs(rnorm( 10, 5, 5))

d = stack(data.frame(a,b,c))

head(d)
     values ID
  4.007200  1
 28.771526  2
  2.168268  3
  8.700740  4
 3.664153   5
 18.181200  6
```

Now, I want to transform this dataset so that : for each new row of the "values" column, the value of this new row is summed with all previous rows. The desired output should look something like this (of course, ignore the "+" and "=" signs, only one single value in the "values" column):

```
   values                                                    ID
  4.007200                                                   1
 4.007200 + 28.771526  = 32.77873                            2
  2.168268 + 4.007200 + 28.771526 = 34.94699                 3
```

Using this previous question ([Cumulative Sum using next column/row in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020619/cumulative-sum-using-next-column-row-in-r)), I tried to do this with the "dplyr" library:

```
    library(dplyr)
    
    final_file = d %>% mutate(cumsum = cumsum(values))

      values ID    cumsum
1   4.007200  1   4.00720
2  28.771526  2  32.77873
3   2.168268  3  34.94699
4   8.700740  4  43.64773
```

This appears to have worked fine. But is there a way to do this in base R?

Thanks

Comment: `d$cumsum <- cumsum(d$values)`

Comment: `cumsum` function is in `base`. `d$cumsum <- cumsum(d$values)` will do the same

Comment: Also `final_file = transform(d, cumsum = cumsum(values))` is all base R